# "field not visible" error in Java

Tags: java

i'm new to programming, so i'm just trying out some simple programs...

```
  public class simple {
        public static void main(String[] args) {        
        A ob=new A(10,20);
        System.out.println("values of a and b are "+ob.a+" "+ob.b);
        }                                                    ^
    }                                                        ^


public class A {
    int a;
    private int b;
    A(){}
    A(int c,int d)
    {
        a=c;
        b=d;
    }
}
```

error displayed was `field ob.b not visible`..i'm using eclipse, need to know what is wrong with the above code..

Thank you!

Comment: Does it even compile?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No. And that's his problem, he should have specified that.

Comment: @Oren Homework questions are explicitly on topic (if well written, just like everything else)

Comment: Instead of just asking "what is wrong with my program" and leaving all the hard work on us, try to show any attempts you have made, errors you see and so on. Being new to programming is not an excuse for not doing your own research.

Comment: While Amith003 has been able to diagnose this successfully it is often easier to figure out exactly what is wrong if you include the error messages you recieve

Comment: First, start your classe name with a Capital letter (`Simple`). Second, say what kind of errors are you having?

Comment: sorry about that, will try and improve my questions in future

Comment: @GayathriDevi Your question is 90% better than most peoples first attempts, take it as advice to be even better

Comment: @RichardTingle Nice to see experienced people encouraging the new one's with positive thoughts

Comment: Please formulate a real question in your title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you notice the variable **b** is declared as private, this will not allow class **simple** to access it directly. Instead you could access it through a method like **getb()**

```
public class A {
    int a;
    private int b;
    A(){}
    A(int c,int d)
    {
        a=c;
        b=d;
    }   
    int getb()
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

Now you can rewrite the **print** statement as follows,

```
System.out.println("values of a and b are "+ob.a+" "+ob.getb());
```

Comment: Fast and furious. +1.

Comment: I'm not sure I could read the question, diagnose it, write this answer all in 1 minute 4 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Object `b` has been declared as `private`, this means you cannot access it from a different class.
You have two options in this case, the first is to declare a and b as public variable, which is considered a bad programming habit since it breaks encapsulation.

Alternatively you could introduce *getter* methods into `class A` as such:

```
public int getA(){
    return a;
}

public int getB(){
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Maroun, thanks for the edits, it's a lot neater now, much appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class simple {
        public static void main(String[] args) {        
        A ob=new A(10,20);
        System.out.println("values of a and b are "+ob.a+" "+ob.b);
        }
    }


public class A {
    int a;
    int b;
    A(){}
    A(int c,int d)
    {
        a=c;
        b=d;
    }
}
```

This will work now.Remove the private access specifier.

Comment: Don't you want to add an explanation? How do you think he'll learn from his mistakes? Or at least format your answer..

Comment: -1 for not even attempting to click on the code button in the editor.